# What does "Snippet Expansion" mean?

Tags: ide

I often heard Snippet Expansion by an IDE, but I searched and couldn't figure out that it means. Could you explain what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means typing in a sequence of characters, e.g. "if()", pressing a keystroke, and having the IDE look up in a database for the replacement, e.g. "if(|) {\n}", and putting it in the editor in place of the sequence.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Snippet expansion in Vim]

Snippet expansion allows you to type short sequences of characters, hit another key, and have it expanded out into a larger amount of code. This is useful for quickly writing common chunks of code.

The above image shows me writing a simple C++ program with the use of snippet expansion. I include the header, I just write `inc` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>. To write the main function, I write `main` and hit <kbd>tab</kbd>. Similarly for the `for` loop and `cout` expression.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Which IDE are you using? I am looking for some packages for IDEs of Python, C, C++, ..., under Emacs. (2) How do you generate that pretty video?

Comment: @Tim (1) This is Vim. (2) Using Quicktime Player on Mac (then converting the .mov to .gif).

Comment: I am not a Vim user. I hope that I can find similar under Emacs.

Comment: @Tim Looks like [Yasnippet](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Yasnippet) is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

It is the feature of some ide's to expand on a certain sequence of keys which is useful to type something faster on not type it at all. Like when you start typing for and it expands to a for loop.

Personally, I use vim, and snipMate.vim enables just that. The example video is [here](http://vimeo.com/3535418).